# Scala Count Lines in a file VERY FAST

Tags: scala, count, scala-collections

Count lines in a file (With BufferedInputStream) in Scala.

```
   object CountLinesScala {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = countLines("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta")
    println(c)
  }

  def countLines(filename: String): Int = {
    val is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))
    try {
      val c = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
      var count = 0
      var readChars = 0
      var empty = true
      while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
        empty = false
        for (i <- 0 until readChars if c(i) == '\n') {
          count=count +1
        }
      }
      if ((count == 0 && !empty)) 1 else count
    } finally {
      is.close()
    }
  }
}
```

its not working, Why ?
i click run but there is no reaction, and no Errors !

Comment: You're never incrementing count.

Comment: thats not the problem, i think !! i think its somewhere here " while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {..."

Comment: It's not going to count if you don't increment your counter.

Comment: i did it now, but iam at the same Problem. "multiple markers at this line comparing values of types Unit and int using '!=' will always yield true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not working because the type of an assignation is `Unit` and you are comparing `Unit` to an `Int` (-1) which can never be equal, therefore your while loop never exits.

More specifically, this expression has type `Unit`

```
(readChars = is.read(c))
```

if you want to fix your version of the program you could define an internal function doRead

```
  def doRead: Int = {
    readChars = is.read(c)
    readChars
  }
```

and use that in your while loop

```
  while (doRead != -1) {
    empty = false
    for (i <- 0 until readChars if c(i) == '\n') {
      count=count +1
    }
  }
```

the final code for countLine would look like

```
def countLines(filename: String): Int = {
    val is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))
    try {
      val c = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
      var count = 0
      var readChars = 0
      var empty = true
      def doRead: Int = {
        readChars = is.read(c)
        readChars
      }
      while (doRead!= -1) {
        empty = false
        for (i <- 0 until readChars if c(i) == '\n') {
          count=count +1
        }
      }
      if ((count == 0 && !empty)) 1 else count
    } finally {
      is.close()
    }
  }
```

However I advise you not to write Scala code like this. As was answered by brian, the most idiomatic way to write this would be to use the scala standard library and write

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta").getLines.size
```

Then your original program would become

```
import scala.io.Source

object CountLinesScala {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = Source.fromFile("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta").getLines().size
    println(c)
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your explaining i understand what u did but i still have an error at  this point "while (doRead)!= -1) ...." . its funny i just write the same Code in java and its works immediately ... sometimes i think Scala is harder than java .

Comment: there should be no closing paren after doRead, sorry for the typo. Scala discourages the use of mutable constructs, which is why you find it harder to write mutable code than it is in java.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library handles this nicely.

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta").getLines.size
```

Comment: how should i do that ? val c = countLines(scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta").getLines.size) , like that ?

Comment: I'd do something like `val numLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/.../Motifs/mrr569.fasta").getLines.size`. The `countLines` method is unnecessary.

Comment: yes, it works thanks !!! and its a good idea .. but do u have any idea why my code don't work ?